# How can TFS Online project with Git version control include multiple Visual Studio solutions?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and TFS online:

I am new to TFS online with Git version control. I am used to classic TFS source control and I am trying to adopt Visual Studio Online Git version control.

With TFS source control model, I can easily have multiple Visual Studio solutions in one TFS online Project. I have done that before and it works well.

I like to do the same thing with TFS online and Git version control. My understanding is that the TFS project has only one Git repository. If I have multiple VS solution in its subfolders, Visual Studio does not know that the solution's parent folder is a repository with a ".git" in it.

How can TFS Online project with Git source control include multiple Visual Studio solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For visual studio online with git version control:

1. Each project can has multiple git repositories. You can add git repo by new repository shows in the picture.

   [image]
2. And each git repo can has multiple solutions. You can add new solutions by VS -> Team explorer -> new for solutions (you should clone the VSO project first) which show as the below picture.

[image]

The new added solutions will in the same directory of `.git` folder, that means the new solutions are version controlled by the same git repository.

**Update**

Other ways to add solutions for a git repo:

A.  VS -> file -> new -> project -> select the local repo directory for **Location** -> don’t select Create new Git repository -> OK
[image]

B.  In the local repo path, copy solutions in it. These files are also added to the git repo, just go to vs and commit the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. The item#2 you mentioned is very interesting, but I like to know how it works behind the scenes. Does VS check the parent folder of the .sln solution for the .git folder?

Comment: For the item #2, it helps a lot if you could refer me to a documentation or article shows how multiple VS .sln solution can reside and tracked in a single .git repository - if I understand your comments correctly.

Comment: There are many confusions around the item#2. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094431/should-git-repos-be-at-the-solution-level-or-project-level-in-visual-studio  I really appreciate if you can refer me to an article explains how #2 works. It is really interesting!

Comment: @AllanXu I think spending some time reading up on how Git works would help you understand your scenario better.

Comment: @AllanXu As vs is working on the local repo, when you add solutions through team explorer, this operation is still within git repository. So it’s unnecessary for vs to check. And there is no official  document now. I added other two ways to add solutions for your reference.

Comment: @AllanXu We are discussing ways of adding solutions to a git repo. The post you mentioned is nearly another structure: multiple git repositorties with multiple projects. And this is the document  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server of add files for TFVC version control, maybe some reference value for you.

Comment: @DanielMann, I agree. I know some basic Git. I seem that Git client checks the parent folder for repositories. Do you know any article that explains this in more depth? Appreciate it.